# Using watir-webdriver, is it possible to use part of an element to test

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

Using watir-webdriver, is it possible to test using part of a 'href' or 'src' elements? For example, I have:

`<a href="/auctions/14807"> Growing Nursing Home</a>`

and I just want to use (href =>/auctions/) instead of the whole string.

I've tried to look and all I could find were solutions to using part text elements. Any help would be greatly received. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can locate an element based on its part of its href or src. Most of the locators allow comparison against a string (ie exact match) or a regular expression (ie for partial matching).

You should be able to click your link using:

```
browser.link(:href => /auctions/).click
```